# VBA - run time error 424: object required

Tags: excel, vba, types

I got an error of run time error 424: object required. I am stuck in creating a formula to calculate standard deviation. I guess I did something wrong by defining type of range. Any suggestions?

```
Sub result()
    ' I can see the average
    MsgBox Application.Average(getRangeByYear(2, year))
    ' Error is caused in here
    MsgBox sdExcludesZero(getRangeByYear(2, year))
End sub

Function meanExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
    Dim count As Double
    Dim sum As Double
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            sum = sum + cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    meanExcludesZero = sum / count
End Function

Function sdExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
    Dim mean As Double
    mean = meanExcludesZero(r)
    Dim sumOfSquareDiff As Double, count As Double
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            sumOfSquareDiff = sumOfSquareDiff + (cell.Value - mean) * (cell.Value - mean)
        End If
    Next cell
    sdExcludesZero = Application.sqrt(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
End Function

Function getRangeByYear(column As Integer, year As Integer)
    ...
    ...
    getRangeByYear = Range(Cells(startIndex, column), Cells(endIndex, column))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with code.

1. `getRangeByYear` returns `Variant` while parameter passed to `sdExcludesZero` is `Excel.Range` (accordingly, `cell.Value` changes to `cell`)
2. Instead of `Application.sqrt` use `Sqr`

See the code below.

```
Sub result()
    ' I can see the average
    MsgBox Application.Average(getRangeByYear(2, year))
    ' Error is caused in here
    MsgBox sdExcludesZero(getRangeByYear(2, year))
End Sub

'Function meanExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
Function meanExcludesZero(r As Variant)
    Dim count As Double
    Dim sum As Double
    For Each cell In r
        'If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        If cell <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            'sum = sum + cell.Value
            sum = sum + cell
        End If
    Next cell
    meanExcludesZero = sum / count
End Function

'Function sdExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
Function sdExcludesZero(r As Variant)
    Dim mean As Double
    mean = meanExcludesZero(r)
    Dim sumOfSquareDiff As Double, count As Double
    For Each cell In r
        'If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        If cell <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            'sumOfSquareDiff = sumOfSquareDiff + (cell.Value - mean) * (cell.Value - mean)
            sumOfSquareDiff = sumOfSquareDiff + (cell - mean) * (cell - mean)
        End If
    Next cell
    'sdExcludesZero = Application.sqrt(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
    sdExcludesZero = Sqr(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
End Function

Function getRangeByYear(column As Integer, year As Integer)
    '...
    '...
    getRangeByYear = Range(Cells(startIndex, column), Cells(endIndex, column))
End Function
```

I've commented lines that needs to be changed and added new line below it. Let me know if anything is not clear.

*Suggestion:* Instead of `cell` use any other variable name.

---

***EDIT :*** You just have to change the return type of function `getRangeByYear` to `Range`. Hence use,

```
Set getRangeByYear = Range(Cells(startIndex, column), Cells(endIndex, column))
```

instead of

```
getRangeByYear = Range(Cells(startIndex, column), Cells(endIndex, column))
```

Another change will be to replace

```
sdExcludesZero = Application.sqrt(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
```

with

```
sdExcludesZero = Sqr(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
```

See the complete code below.

```
Sub result()
    ' I can see the average
    MsgBox Application.Average(getRangeByYear(2, year))
    ' Error is caused in here
    MsgBox sdExcludesZero(getRangeByYear(2, year))
End Sub

Function meanExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
    Dim count As Double
    Dim sum As Double
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            sum = sum + cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    meanExcludesZero = sum / count
End Function

Function sdExcludesZero(r As Excel.Range)
    Dim mean As Double
    mean = meanExcludesZero(r)
    Dim sumOfSquareDiff As Double, count As Double
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
            count = count + 1
            sumOfSquareDiff = sumOfSquareDiff + (cell.Value - mean) * (cell.Value - mean)
        End If
    Next cell
    'sdExcludesZero = Application.sqrt(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
    sdExcludesZero = Sqr(sumOfSquareDiff / count)
End Function

Function getRangeByYear(column As Integer, year As Integer) As Range
    '...
    '...
    Set getRangeByYear = Range(Cells(startIndex, column), Cells(endIndex, column))
End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot. much clear now. was confusing about the type of range and variant

Comment: @PakHoCheung - You just have to change the return type of function `getRangeByYear`. See edit in answer.

Comment: What is the difference of using set? Is it something like memory allocation?

Comment: @PakHoCheung - The `Set` keyword is used to create new objects. See [this](http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_set_keyword.html) for details.